# Can't figure out what the syntax error is for this MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to MySQL and am trying to write a basic procedure that deletes all the email addresses that are not in the correct format. In this case, a invalid email address is anything that does not have an @ symbol anywhere in the email.

But when I try to execute the query, it gives me the error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 4. This is the query I have so far.

```
Create Procedure DeleteInvalidEmail ()
Begin
    DELETE FROM mockdata__2_ WHERE email NOT REGEXP '@+'
END
```

I was using the MySQL documentation example so I'm really not sure whats wrong

Comment: Your delete command requires a ; at the end.

Comment: Your SP contains only one stmt, so BEGIN-END not needed. And Regex usage is excess if you check for `@` char presence only. So simply `CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteInvalidEmail () DELETE FROM mockdata__2_ WHERE LOCATE('@', email);`. And delimiters reassign not needed too.